# Single sign on 10 different web sites

Tags: php

I have 10 websites with different PHP related platforms like in Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress and Core PHP etc (Even includes sub domains also).

I want to create one new website with Registration and login functionality in Core PHP or else any framework. I want to implement single sign on functionality through this latest web site. So that can any one let me know the process to finish this.

Comment: Thanks Peter..any idea to move forward

Comment: this site is for solving problems. what is the problem you faced with?

Comment: Peter, Struck in where to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a pre-built single sign-on system to integrate with your projects, you may want to check out:

http://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/

The SSO client can be integrated as a plugin into Drupal, Joomla, WordPress, etc.  Basically, override their login system with the SSO server/client system.  Finding plugins for it at the moment is a bit difficult since it is relatively new software.

Comment: @ThirupathiVemula: You should also accept the answer if this solution works for you. See this thread for how to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work